# Add new upload file format (.dcm) in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to upload .dcm(Xrays,CT Scan images) format files for some reason.

So I need to add `.dcm` file type in WordPress allowed file type list.

Anyone please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a set of restricted file types it will allow you to upload via the media library. Whilst this is a great security feature, there may be times where you’d like to add other files that are restricted by default, or maybe even the opposite where you’d only like to allow a few extensions to be uploaded.

Fortunately, WordPress makes this dead easy with a small snippet of PHP code.

If you’d like to add or remove a specific file type that can be uploaded to WordPress via the media library, you can insert this PHP code in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function my_myme_types($mime_types){
    //Adjust the $mime_types, which is an associative array where the key is extension and value is mime type.
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1);
```

Here is an example of what you can do to add and remove a new file type (in this example, I’m adding an extension that already exists, but the concept is the same):

```
function my_myme_types($mime_types){
    $mime_types['avi'] = 'video/avi'; //Adding avi extension
    unset($mime_types['pdf']); //Removing the pdf extension
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1);
```

You can also reset the allowed file types by creating a new array within the function and returning these values:

```
function my_myme_types($mime_types){
    //Creating a new array will reset the allowed filetypes
    $mime_types = array(
        'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'bmp' => 'image/bmp',
        'tif|tiff' => 'image/tiff'
    );
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1);
```

If you’d like to see what file types are currently supported by WordPress, check out the function `get_allowed_mime_types()` located in the `wp-includes/functions.php` file.